# Relationship between dynamic range and number of samples

Tags: digital-logic, digital-communications

I am working on an NI measurement system. I tried to measure the dynamic range of the system and I got about 100 dB.

On this system I can easily change the number of samples per average (for example, from 100 samples per average to 10k samples per average). When I do that, the dynamic range changes by about 20 dB.

The question is, how can I confirm by calculation that the change in dynamic range that I got is right - knowing that the receiver resolution is 16 bit?

Comment: What are you sampling? Is the input signal fluctuating? If it is, you will clearly have an apparent change in DR as your sample interval extends to include larger (and smaller) signal levels.

Comment: I mean by samples per average is taking the average of the measured voltage. for example if the number of samples for each value is 10000 samples then I will take the average of those samples to get one value. I wish that answer your question

Comment: I understand that. I'm asking about the voltage which you are measuring. Is that voltage fluctuating? Is it a sine wave, noise, something else?

Comment: yes it is at the noise floor

Comment: And when you said the dynamic range changes by 20 dB, do you mean it got worse (i.e. closer to 80 dB total), or better (towards 120 dB)?

Comment: I've measured -65 dbm noise floor when i used 10k samples per average and -45 dbm when I used 100 sample per average

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're seeing is the power law of white phase noise. As you average, you'll see the stability (or accuracy in your case) of your estimation will drop in proportion to your averaging time, as seen here:
[image: stability]

Using the plot, as your averaging time changes from 1 to 100 (which is the same as your 100 points to 10,000), the vertical axis drops to 10<sup>-2</sup>:

this equates to 10*log(100) = 20 dB, which makes your measurement almost perfect!

Comment: sorry is it 10 or 23 dB ???

Comment: @Thoalfukar oops, good catch. Typo.

Comment: @Thoalfukar actually. Did I make an error? Give me a moment

Comment: @Thoalfukar Ok. Fixed. I used the wrong noise process when creating the plot. I used random-walk instead of white. Still 20 dB.

Comment: @Thoalfukar Very welcome. A couple of notes: 1. Why did I originally write 23 dB? I can’t figure that out. Edited to the obviously correct 20 dB (which makes your results even better.) 2. Note that this relationship will only hold for so long. Eventually your averaging will cease to improve your approximations- at this point you have reached the “flicker floor”, which is a different noise process.

Answer (score 1):

Theoretically if you take two identical signals and average (in the presence of benign noise) you get a 3 dB increase in signal to noise ratio. Consider two identical signals with different background noises having same RMS noise amplitudes...

When you add the two waveforms (signal and noise), the signal doubles because they are the same individually (6 dB increase) but the total noise only goes up by 3 dB because the individual noise sources are not coherent. Hence SNR rises by 3 dB. Take 4 samples and you get a 6 dB improvement. Take 16 samples and you get a 12 dB improvement.

Take 64 samples and you get an 18 dB improvement. So, with 100x oversampling you'll get something like a 20 dB improvement.

Comment: Sorry, I did not get you exactly. actually I wanted to use a formula to calculate that

Comment: Which bit didn’t you understand.... the bit of adding two identical signals produces 6 dB gain or adding two non coherent noise signals only gives 3 dB gain?

Comment: sorry to reply very late, actually I am looking for the equation that link between the vector averaging and the noise floor. your example make it a little bit difficult to link between what I am looking for and your example. many thanks

Comment: I'm unsure what you mean by vector averaging. Maybe go google "dithering to reduce noise". There are a few articles online with formulas but in case you wanted to know the RMS of two non-coherent signals it's \$\sqrt{A^2+B^2}\$ where A and B are the individual RMS terms.